# Java Regex: how to find the total number of occurrences of matching strings from a txt file?

Tags: regex, junit

The instructor gave us a text file which contains a book, and we're supposed to find the number of times a word is used which does not contains "aeio."

Here's the full question for clarifications sake:

> create a Junit test that tests the total number of occurrences of
>   words that do not contain the letters a, e, i, or o. Note that this
>   test differs from the others in that it finds the total number of
>   occurrences of matching strings, not just the number of matching
>   strings. Assert that the number of occurrences is 1347.

Here's a copied test from the code that he gave us, but I think it's very close to what the answer should be...I just can't figure this one out.

```
    @Test
public void testCapuletOrCapulets() {
    //count number of times a word doesn't contain a,e,i or o
    String matchString = "^aeio" ;
    File f = new File("romeojuliet.txt");
    WordFrequency wf = new WordFrequency(f);
    wf.buildTree();
    Map<String, Integer> map = wf.getFrequencies();
    int numMatches = 0;
    for(String s: map.keySet()) if(s.matches(matchString.toLowerCase())) numMatches++;
    assertEquals(numMatches, 1347);
}
```

Comment: I've only tried different matchstrings, like "String matchString = "^aeio" ;"...also "\\b[^aeio]\\b" but they dont work...

Comment: I think what you really need is to study more regex.  I don't want to tell you the answer because you will not really be learning anything.  Go to http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and go through the tutorial.  Everything is explained very well.  You can use http://regexpal.com/ to test regex's out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this:

```
    @Test
public void testCapuletOrCapulets() {
    //count number of times a word doesn't contain a,e,i or o
    String matchString = "aeio" ;
    File f = new File("romeojuliet.txt");
    WordFrequency wf = new WordFrequency(f);
    wf.buildTree();
    Map<String, Integer> map = wf.getFrequencies();
    int numMatches = 0;
    int numAll = 0;
    for(String s: map.keySet()){
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()){
            if(matchString.contains(c)){
                numMatches++;
                break;
            }
        }
        numAll++;
    }  
    assertEquals(numAll - numMatches, 1347);
}
```

Not entirely sure if it's plug and play, because i couldn't test it right now.
What it does is split the string into a char array and matches the char against the matchString. If the matchString contains the char then numMatches goes up and we'll move on to the next word (hence break the inner for-loop). 
Because you need to count words which don't contain given letters then you would need to also count the total number of words and then subtract the matches from total word count.

I am sure there are better solutions, but this should also work.